# @Autowired throwing null-pointer in StepDef file

Tags: java, spring-boot, cucumber, bdd

Cucumber runner configuration :
path: /test/java/com.example.ndod

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:feature",plugin = {"pretty"})
public class NdodApplicationTests {
}
```

Step Definition file:
path: /test/java/com.example.ndod

```
@SpringBootTest
public class NdodStepdefs{

    @Autowired
    Service service;

...
}
```

Feature file:
path: /test/resources

```
Feature: Ndod RestAPI

  Scenario: Call NdodApi to get JSON result
    Given Create a NdodApi
    When Call NdodApi with "ATS8594"
    Then Get result in Json
```

pom.xml:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: paste stacktrace please

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.Stepdefs.callApiWith(Stepdefs.java:37)
 at ?.When Call Api with "ATS8594"

Comment: Do you have the `Service` type registered in your DI container? What is the implementing class?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: I'm still not seeing anything related to registering the Service class with the DI container.

Comment: Where are you defining the `Service` bean to be autowired? (Sidenote: you are using a very old version of cucumber; consider updating to `<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>` and a more recent version)

Comment: Service is my java class where my business logic is written and which is annotated as @Service